# Trying to understand an exercise about differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the second exercise of the free version of the book of Teschl *ODE and dynamical systems*:

> [image: exercise]

What I have done is this: it can be written that

$$\ddot r\big(1+r_0(t)\epsilon+r_1(t)\epsilon^2+\mathcal O(\epsilon^3)\big)^2=-\gamma M\epsilon^2$$

Thus

$$\ddot r\big(1+2r_0(t)\epsilon+(2r_1(t)+r_0(t)^2)\epsilon^2+\mathcal O(\epsilon^3)\big)=-\gamma M\epsilon^2$$

what imply that

$$\ddot r(t)+\ddot r(t) 2r_0(t)\epsilon+(\ddot r(t)2r_1(t)+\ddot r(t)r_0(t)^2+\gamma M)\epsilon^2+\mathcal O(\epsilon^3)=0$$

But I dont know exactly what I must done here. The hints provided seems obscure, I dont know how setup "differential equations for $r_0(t),r_1(t),\ldots$".

---

UPDATE: I finally solved it. It can be written that

$$\ddot r\big(1+2r\epsilon+r^2\epsilon^2)=-\gamma M\epsilon^2$$

Then writing $r(t,\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k(t)\epsilon^k$ and $\ddot r(t,\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\ddot r_k(t)\epsilon^k$, and equating the coefficients of power series of both sides we get

$$\ddot r_0=0,\quad 2\ddot r_0r_0+\ddot r_1=0\implies \ddot r_1=0\\\implies\ddot r_2r_0=-\gamma M,\quad\ddot r_2\big(r_1+2r_0\big)+\ddot r_3=0\tag1$$

Also observe that, from the initial conditions $r(0)=h$ and $\dot r(0)=0$ we have

$$r(0,\epsilon)-h=-h+\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k(0)\epsilon^k=0\implies \begin{matrix}r_0(0)=h\\r_k(0)=0,\forall k\in\Bbb N_{>0}\end{matrix}\tag2$$

$$\dot r(0,\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dot r_k(0)\epsilon^k=0\implies \dot r_k(0)=0,\,\forall k\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}\tag3$$

Integrating $\ddot r_0=0$ we knows that $$r_0=K_1 t+K_2,\qquad\dot r_0=K_1\tag4$$ then by $(2)$ and $(3)$ we find that $r_0=h$, and by $(1)$ and $(3)$ we also knows that $\dot r_1=0$, and by $(2)$ consequently $r_1=0$.

And integrating, together with the results of $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get

$$r_2=-\frac{\gamma M}{2h} t^2,\quad\ddot r_3=2\gamma M\implies r_3=\gamma Mt^2$$

Hence finally we reach the expression

$$r(t)=h-g\frac{t^2}{2h}+g\frac{t^2}R+\mathcal O(1/R^4),\quad g=\frac{\gamma M}{R^2}$$

Comment: You reed to write $\ddot{r} = \ddot{r_0} + \epsilon \ddot{r_1} + \epsilon^2\ddot{r_2} + \epsilon^3\ddot{r_3} + \cal{O}(\epsilon^4)$. Also I think there are missing terms in what you already wrote.